# light switch 3 amp enough for a 4 watt led light set

Tags: lighting

Can i install a 3 amp switch next to a light? The led light is 4 watts.  The light is for installing under the top cabinet. I have 3 such lights to be installed under the top cabinets. There is already a switch for all 3 but i want to switch off one such light that i may not need.

Comment: Where are you on this planet, and what make and model of light switch do you wish to use?

Comment: Do they run on low voltage, or are they mains voltage (120V or 230V)?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: yes, you can, 100% for sure. You're using (likely far) less than 2 amps.